# Read view row entities and create a node for each entity

Tags: views, entities, 9

I have a view that looks like in the following screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

I am creating a custom action to publish selected comments and create a node for each comment. The custom action code is the following.

```php
class publishtraction extends ViewsBulkOperationsActionBase {
  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function execute($entity = NULL, $view = NULL) {
    // Publish the selected comment.
    $entity->setPublished(TRUE)->save();
    
    // Create a node for the selected comment.
    
    // Don't return anything for a default completion message; otherwise return translatable markup.
    return $this->t('Some result');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access($object, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {
    if ($object->getEntityType() === 'node') {
      $access = $object->access('update', $account, TRUE)
        ->andIf($object->status->access('edit', $account, TRUE));
      return $return_as_object ? $access : $access->isAllowed();
    }

    // Other entity types may have different access methods and properties.
    return TRUE;
  }

}
```

My custom action is publishing/unpublishing the comments correctly. However, as next step, I want to read the multiselect field and the selected view row entities values to show them with `var_dump()`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is your goal to display the row entities without a full page refresh - i.e. via some ajax method?

Comment: My goal is to publish the selected items and create a node on the selected content type. I want that to happen at the same action. Without a page refresh would work.